# Can midpoints of a class be used instead of upper boundaries in cumulative frequency graphs?

Tags: frequency

I know that we use upper class boundaries while sketching ogives but in an example my professor used midpoints while sketching a cumulative frequency polygon. I'm wondering is it okay to do like that.

Comment: please clarify, give an illustrative example etc.

Comment: In http://onlinestatbook.com/2/graphing_distributions/freq_poly.html the author also uses midpoints while sketching cumulative frequency polygon, but doesn't doing that is bad practice because it causes ignoring values bigger than the midpoint of the class? or is it okay because midpoint is used for representing the whole class?